# Get mean value of certain part of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 0, 2, 22, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 0, 1, 34, 99, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 0, 5, 11, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 0, 6, -5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 0, 88, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                  [ 1, 1, 333, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I want to get the mean values of a certain part of my area. The areas center is at the index `[3][4]` and goes 5 steps to each direction.

I thought one approach would be to create a sub array for the area of interested and use `numpy.mean` on that sub array. How could I create that sub array?

Also I am interested in other approaches or ideas.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you face any problems or did not know how to approach it at all after reading the tutorials?

Comment: If the center is at 3, 4 and it goes 5 steps in each direction, won't that go past the end of the array? Also, do you want a rectangular slice, or a roughly circular thing?

Comment: Yes, this would go past the end of the array. The sub array is in that case just cut of. Rectangular and circular both work. Circular is preferred though.

Comment: What you want to do is to [slice the array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html), and then call `np.mean(...)` on the sliced array.  It's not creating a new array, just looking at part of it.

Comment: @askewchan Yes, that would work. If you post this as an answer with an example for my case, I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to make a rectangular slice of the array:

```
>>> span = 5
>>> a[0:3+span+1, 0:4+span+1]
array([[  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
       [  1,   1,   4,   3,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
       [  1,   0,   2,  22,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0],
       [  1,   0,   1,  34,  99,   1,   1,   0,   1],
       [  1,   0,   5,  11,   0,   1,   1,   0,   1],
       [  1,   0,   6,  -5,   0,   1,   1,   0,   1],
       [  1,   0,  88,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0],
       [  1,   1, 333,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1]])
```

Of course, the mean of this is:

```
>>> np.mean(a[0:3+5, 0:4+5])
8.9305555555555554
```

To get a circular slice, you could use:

```
i, j = np.indices(a.shape)
a[((i-3)**2 < 25) & ((j-4)**2 < 25)]
```

Comment: How is this centered about (3,4) in a distance of 5 in each direction? This always slices from the left (0,0) corner, no?

Comment: Symmitchry Yes, the left edge is included within 5, see @schreon's answer and my comment there for a better way to include the left edge without going over.  The true answer here is the circular 'slice', which OP preferred.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I was thinking of the general case. (Also, the circular slice is very cool stuff.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a long  form version that walks you through the steps:

```
def center_mean(array, row, col, size):

    # Use min & max to handle edges
    row_min = max(0, row - size)
    row_max = min(len(array), row + size)

    col_min = max(0, col-size)
    col_max = min(len(array[0]), col + size)

    # Get just the rows we want:
    sub_rows = array[row_min:row_max + 1]

    total = 0.0
    for row in sub_rows:
        # Now take just the cols we want:
        new_row = row[col_min:col_max + 1]
        total += sum(new_row)

    return total / (size*2 + 1)**2


print(center_mean(array, 3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: This answer has the best handling of the range, but don't be afraid to use numpy :P  Once you've defined your ranges, just use: `np.mean(array[row_min:row_max+1, col_min:col_max+1])`

Answer (score 1):

```
i,j=3,4
m = array[max(0,i-5):i+5,max(0,j-5):j+5].mean()
```

Note: In the case of your center (3,4), the sub area will actually be of the shape (8,9) instead of (11,11), because it is cut off at the borders.

Comment: Nice way to deal with overlap with the edges, but you should do it for both sides: `array[max(0,i-5):min(i+6, array.shape[0]),max(0,j-5):min(j+6, array.shape[1])]`  btw, even if `i,j` are far enough from edges your code would give `(10,10)` not `(11,11)` since the end of the slice is not included, which is why I've used `i+6` instead of `i+5`.